# Bugs un-understandable: var considered sometimes as list and sometimes as str

Tags: python, string, list, file, attributes

Here is a very strange bugs that I cannot understand at all on *Python*.
The instructions hereunder give details on what the function should do.

The f and f2 creation and writing are working well. I test the function with an example :  `histo_appels(['bob','jean','bob'],['21/03','22/03','28/03])`.

*Python* gives me an error message :

> line = line.split() // list object has no attribute 'split'.

But in my function, line should be a string extracted from f.

It means that before I did `line = line.split()`, line was already a list. So okay, I try directly to do `line.extend(line2)` and this time, Python returns an error message:

> line.extend(line2)  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'

It means that line is this time a string, whereas it was said to be a list just before ...

Any ideas ?

```
def histo_appels(liste_contact, liste_date):
        liste = []
        s = set(liste_contact)
        l = list(s)
        # we identify the contact that try to call me 
        # set to remove doubles: ['bob','jean','bob'] becomes ['bob','jean']
        chaine = str(liste_contact)
        # count() can only be applied to a string

        f = open(r'c:\temp\historique_contact.txt','w',encoding='utf8')
        for i in range(len(s)):
            liste.append((l[i],chaine.count(l[i])))
            f.write(f"{l[i]} tried to call you {chaine.count(l[i])} time\n")
        f.close()
        # example : line 1 of f contains "bob tried to call you 2 time", 
        # and line 2 : "jean tried to call you 1 time"

        f2 = open(r'c:\temp\historique_date.txt','w',encoding='utf8')
        for i in s:
            liste1 = []
            for j in range(len(liste_contact)):
                if liste_contact[j] == i:
                    liste1.append(liste_date[j])
            f2.write(f"on the {liste1}\n")
            # example line 1 of f2 is "on the ['21/03','28/03']"
            # and line 2 of f2 is : "on the ['22/03']
        f2.close()

        # then we merge each line of f with f2 in a new file f3
        f = open(r'c:\temp\historique_contact.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
        f2 = open(r'c:\temp\historique_date.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
        f3 = open(r'c:\temp\historique_global.txt','w',encoding='utf8')
        for line in f:
            for line2 in f2:
                line = line.split()
                # on repasse line (=str) en liste
                line2 = line2.split()
                line.extend(line2)
                f3.write(" ".join(line))
        f3.close()
        f2.close()
        f.close()
```

Comment: You're running `line = line.split()` on the same `line` multiple times inside a loop.  Whatever you were trying to do, that is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the nested `for` loop:

```
for line in f:
    for line2 in f2:
        line = line.split()
        # on repasse line (=str) en liste
        line2 = line2.split()
        line.extend(line2)
        f3.write(" ".join(line))
```

When you enter the second `for` loop, you are continuosly splitting `line`, reassigning his value. I do not understand what you want to do, but that specific problem is solved py calling `split` on `line` in the correct for loop:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.split()
    for line2 in f2:
        # on repasse line (=str) en liste
        line2 = line2.split()
        line.extend(line2)
        f3.write(" ".join(line))
```